# python readfile and match regex based on another lines value under the match

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm looping through the lines of a bunch of files and need to find any sections that start with:

```
\[.+\]
```

Which works fine. But then I only want that line that matches **if** underneath it there's a line that DOESN'T say "disabled = 1"  OR "disabled=1"  OR "disabled = true" OR "disabled=true". Check all the lines underneath it until end of file OR another

```
\[.+\]
```

is found. If the section is NOT disabled, I want to capture that line and store it in an array.
The code to loop the array and write the new file already works fine. Right now I'm getting ALL header lines in sections disabled or not.

So in the end I want this as my new file based on the below example:

```
[header1:name1]
<some new content>

[header3:name3]
<some new content>

[header4:name4]
<some new content>
```

one FILE's contents

```
[header1:name1]
param1 = value1
param2 = value2
param3 = value3
param4 = value4

[header2:name2]
param1 = value1
param2 = value2
param3 = value3
disabled = 1
param4 = value4

[header3:name3]
disabled = 0
param1 = value1
param2 = value2
param3 = value3
param4 = value4

[header4:name4]
param1 = value1
param2 = value2
param3 = value3
param4 = value4
disabled =false
```

This is a small part of a large script but here's the section on this i have so far which currently works but it picks up ALL matches, even the disabled ones which is the problem.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
    enabled_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk((start_folder)):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith("file.cnf"):
                file_full = ( os.path.join(root, file) )
                if not any(ignore in str(file_full) for ignore in ignore_if_path_contains):
                    if debug:
                        print(file_full)
                    if CheckFilePermission(file_full, "R"):
                        file_full_read = open( (file_full), 'rb' )
                        if (re.search( r'\[.+\]', str(file_full_read.read()) )):
                            if debug:
                                print( "found string in file: "+(file_full) )
                            with open( (file_full), 'r' ) as rfile:
                                for line in rfile.readlines():
                                    if not any(ignore in str(line) for ignore in ignore_if_section_name_contains):
                                        if ( re.search( r'\[.+\]', (line) ) ):
                                            if debug:
                                                print( "found string in line: "+(line) )
                                            enabled_list.append(line)
    enabled_list = list(dict.fromkeys(enabled_list))
    return(enabled_list)
```

**UPDATE: WORKING CODE**
Using suggestion from JD Frias below I extended my already long function with success. Will refine this later but here is the working code all in one. Marking JD's answer correct.

```
    enabled_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk((start_folder)):
        # get all files in specified folder
        for file in files:
            # check only specific files
            if file.endswith("*.cnf"):
                # get full path to file
                file_full = ( os.path.join(root, file) )
                # check if file contains anything in ignore paths list
                if not any(ignore in str(file_full) for ignore in ignore_if_path_contains):
                    if debug:
                        print(file_full)
                    # ensure file is readable
                    if CheckFilePermission(file_full, "R"):
                        file_full_read = open( (file_full), 'rb' )
                        # check if file contains any headers
                        if (re.search( r'\[.+\]', str(file_full_read.read()) )):
                            if debug:
                                print( "found string in file: "+(file_full) )
                            with open( (file_full), 'r' ) as rfile:
                            '''
                            1. open the file
                            2. read the lines
                            3. for each line see if its a header line
                            4. if so check if previous cur_line was valid
                                if so add it to the list since it survived til next header
                            5. otherwise set cur_line to current header found and move on
                            6. if disabled found, clear cur_line and move on
                            '''
                                cur_line = ""
                                for line in rfile.readlines():
                                    if not any(ignore in str(line) for ignore in ignore_if_section_name_contains):
                                        if ( re.search( r'\[.+\]', (line) ) ):
                                            if cur_line:
                                                enabled_list.append(cur_line)
                                                cur_line = ""
                                            if debug:
                                                print( "found string in line: "+(line) )
                                            cur_line = line
                                        elif re.search(r'disabled *= *(true|1)', line):
                                            cur_line = ""
                                            continue
                                # check if cur line valid at EOF since no more loops left
                                if cur_line:
                                    enabled_list.append(cur_line)
                                    cur_line = ""
    enabled_list = list(dict.fromkeys(enabled_list))
    return(enabled_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a separate function to process the lines from: `rfile.readlines()`

```py
def find_enabled(lines):
  name = None
  for line in lines:
    if re.search(r'\[.+\]', line):
      name = line
      # no break, keep going to check if it's enabled
    
    elif re.earch(r'disabled *= *(true|1)', line):
      # found disabled, return None
      return None

  # if we made it this far then we found it with no disabled found or not found at all
  return name
```

On a similar/maintainability note, I would break all this up into tiny little functions that do one thing and one thing only to make it more readable and changes like this much easier.

For multiple blocks in one file the idea is the same, just need to keep track of the last one you found and save it if we haven't seen a disabled block

```py
def find_enabled(lines):
    names = []
    last = None
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(r'\[.*\]', line):
            if last:
                names.append(last)
            last = line

        elif re.search(r'disabled *= *(true|1)', line):
            last = None

    if last:
        names.append(last)

    return names
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but wouldn't this imply that im sending just blocks of linesto the function ? If each block was already "separated" then this would work, but the "filte contents" I posted has multiple blocks. This was the part I was struggling with. If I send all the lines thru this function it would end with ONE header per file which there can be 100 headers in one file. Perhaps my labeling was unclear... all of that file contents is in ONE file :)

Comment: Updated answer to include multiple blocks per file.

Comment: lol thanks! I already actually got it working USING your data flow. I just put it all into the same function. Will clean it up now.. I usually do write a buncha small functions but I had to write this in a hurry initially.. hence the oversight on the "disabled" items. Thanks! See my original post for how I ended up doing it with your original suggestion